# How to show images with original size ratio in table cells - pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt

i made a table with a certain column that holds images and made cells stretch to its content size with the snippet code:

```
headerh.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
headerv.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

so both width and height of cells are adjusted to the content of the cells the problems i'm facing here is that the width and height of all cells are adjusted to the maximum width and height not  wut i want which is adjusting every cell to its own content so all images shows correctly with no over stretching that ruins the size ratio of the image and here is an image shows wut i'm facing:
[image]

i wish there is a way to make the first cell not stretch its content image like that !
and here is the complete code i'm writing without the database !:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,
QVBoxLayout)

import sqlite3
import random


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Arabic Math Project')
        self.setContentsMargins(20,20,20,20)
        # create table:
        self.setStyleSheet("""QTableView::item { border: 0px; padding: 10px;}QTableView{font-size:20px;}QPushButton{width:200px;height:30px}QLineEdit {width:200px;height:50px;}""")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("click it")
        self.searchBar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.searchBar.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.searchBar.setStyleSheet("font-size:35px;")
        self.searchBar.setPlaceholderText("search")
        self.searchBar.textChanged.connect(self.startSearchThreading) #editingFinished()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        
        #cells auto-resizing 
        headerh = self.table.horizontalHeader() 
        headerh.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        headerv = self.table.verticalHeader()
        headerv.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        
        
        
        

        conn = sqlite3.connect("math.db")
        conn.text_factory = bytes
        self.cur = conn.cursor()


        data = self.cur.execute("select * from problems;").fetchall();conn.close()
        self.dims = (lambda x: (len(x), len(x[0])))(data) #(rows number, col number)

        [self.table.insertRow(i) for i in [i for i in range(self.dims[0])]]
        [self.table.insertColumn(i) for i in [i for i in range(self.dims[1]+1)]]

        #changing h-header names .
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Unique", "Image", "Test", "Year", "Lesson", "Comment", "Options", "Options-advanced"])

        for c in range(self.dims[1]):
            for r in range(self.dims[0]):
                if c!=1:self.table.setItem(r, c, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data[r][c].decode("utf-8"))) 
                else:self.table.setCellWidget(r, c, self.getImage(data[r][c]))

        for r in range(self.dims[0]):self.table.setCellWidget(r, self.dims[1], Options(ops=[data[r][self.dims[1]-1].decode("utf-8")]))

        # connect table signals:
        #self.table.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)
        #self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.item_changed)

        
        
        layout.addWidget(self.searchBar)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        
        

    def getImage(self, image):
        imageLabel = QLabel()
        imageLabel.setText('')
        imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(image, "jpg")
        imageLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
        return imageLabel

    def startSearchThreading(self):
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.update = updateTable(data= self.searchBar.text())
        self.update.new_signal.connect(self.Search)
        self.update.start()

    def create(self):
        self.createFormGroupBox()
        return self.formGroupBox

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int, bytes, bool, bytes)
    def Search(self, r, c, d, newRowOrder, ops):
        #print(r, c, d.decode("utf-8"))

        if newRowOrder:self.table.insertRow(self.table.rowCount()) # create new row.        
        if c!=1:self.table.setItem(r, c, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(d.decode("utf-8"))) 
        else:self.table.setCellWidget(r, c, self.getImage(d))

        for r in range(self.dims[1]):self.table.setCellWidget(r, self.dims[1], Options(ops=[ops]))


class updateTable(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, data=True):
        super(QtCore.QThread, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    new_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int, bytes, bool, bytes)

    def run(self):
        currRow = 0
        conn = sqlite3.connect("math.db")
        conn.text_factory = bytes
        self.cur = conn.cursor()
        searched = self.cur.execute(" SELECT * FROM problems WHERE text LIKE ('%' || ? || '%') ", (self.data,)).fetchall()
        dims = (lambda x: (len(x), len(x[0])))(searched) if searched!=[] else (0, 0)
        print(dims)
        for r in range(dims[0]):
            for c in range(dims[1]):
                self.new_signal.emit(r, c, searched[r][c], True if c==0 else False, searched[r][dims[1]-1])
                #if c!=1:self.table.setItem(r, c, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(searched[r][c].decode("utf-8"))) 
                #else:self.table.setCellWidget(r, c, self.getImage(searched[r][c]))

            #self.new_signal.emit(1, 2, searched)



class Options(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, ops=[]):
        super(Options, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("""QTableView::item { border: 0px; padding: 10px;}QTableView{font-size:20px;}QPushButton{width:200px;height:30px}QLineEdit {width:200px;height:50px;}""")
        self.i = random.randint(1, 100)
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Name:"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Country:"), QComboBox())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Age:"), QSpinBox())
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("click")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.do)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        print(ops)
    def do(self):
        print(f"clicked {self.i}")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.resize(600,600)
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Assuming you're using an item delegate, that depends on the returned `sizeHint` and how the `paint` method is implemented. But, if you don't share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we won't be able to help you in any way.

Comment: @musicamante hey buddy, remember me ? i'm the dude from yesterday but this is my other acc the other is banned from asking questions, look here we are again in the same situation where i'm not clear enough sorry for that but i will try to fix this.

Comment: @musicamante i added the whole code  i hope it makes it better to understand my problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a QLabel with `setScaledContents`, it will always try to scale the contents while *ignoring* the aspect ratio.

You can use a subclass of QLabel that overrides the default painting behavior whenever a QPixmap exists and the current size ratio is different from that of the pixmap.

```
class ScaledPixmapLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setScaledContents(True)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.pixmap():
            pm = self.pixmap()
            originalRatio = pm.width() / pm.height()
            currentRatio = self.width() / self.height()
            if originalRatio != currentRatio:
                qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
                pm = self.pixmap().scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
                rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, pm.width(), pm.height())
                rect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
                qp.drawPixmap(rect, pm)
                return
        super().paintEvent(event)


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # ...
    def getImage(self, image):
        imageLabel = ScaledPixmapLabel()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(image, "jpg")
        imageLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
        return imageLabel
```

PS: You don't need to use `setText('')` on a new QLabel, it already has no text.